# Insert "????" in mysql database when post from c# code in Persian language

Tags: c#, mysql, wordpress, entity-framework

i have a problem when i insert a post in mysql database with mysql entity in c#.
The persian letters in inserted record convert to "????" but when i read from database persian contents (that stored before) they're shown very well.

My table collation is UTF8mb4_unicode_520_ci and when I insert post from wordpress is shown well but when I try the same in my code I have the specified problem

Here is my code for inserting in database:

```
wp_posts post = new wp_posts
        {
            post_author = 1,
            post_date = DateTime.Now,
            post_date_gmt = DateTime.Now,
            post_content = "<h2>" + txtPersianContent.Text + "</h2>",
            post_title = txtPersianTitle.Text,
            post_excerpt = "None",
            post_status = "publish",
            comment_status = "open",
            ping_status = "open",
            post_password = "",
            post_name = txtName.Text,
            post_modified = DateTime.Now,
            post_modified_gmt = DateTime.Now,
            guid = txtGUID.Text,
            to_ping = "None",
            pinged = "None",
            post_content_filtered = "None",
            post_parent = 0,
            menu_order = 0,
            post_type = "post",
            post_mime_type = "",
            comment_count = 0
        };
db.wp_posts.Add(post);
db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

[and picture from mysql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJEG0.png)

Please help me to fix this problem ;)

Comment: Sounds like an encoding issue to me.   Is your C# code using the same encoding as your table (UTF8mb4_unicode_520_ci)?

Comment: No my c# code is string because it's insert just string

Comment: Try to debug the `db.wp_posts.Add(post);` line. what does `post.post_content` contain? What does `txtPersianContent.Text` contain?

Comment: @Sklivvz `txtPersianContent.Text  = "سلام به شما کاربران عزیز" `

Comment: What about the other?

Comment: other is not important. first i fixed this problem

Comment: @user9277249 then please document it in an answer so the next person benefits

Comment: Sure
But first I have to find the answer.

Comment: What is your connection string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check your connection string! You should specify Character Set with your connection to mysql:

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword; CharSet=utf8;
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you do anything with non ascii characters, you should first tell your program (PHP, C#, whatever) which encoding it should expect when reading the input. You are probably using encoding that is different from your actual input which will "garble" the text.

Comment: i use string to get or set post

Comment: A string always needs to know the encoding first, BEFORE reading it. If that encoding is indeed correct, you may then need to convert it to the corresponding encoding of your database.

Comment: Also, MySql might not be configured to accept UTF8. What happens if you use the query "SET NAMES utf8" before inserting a record?