# Save Persian Text With Emoji in MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am new to SQL and I don't to know how to save Farsi text (string) with emojis in database.

Do I have to change the collation of database? Right now, its `utf8_persian_ci`.

Comment: This may be a useful read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6642755/insert-a-persian-text-in-mysql-table

Comment: And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27460469/storing-persian-arabic-text-in-mysql-database) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20519496/persian-characters-issue-in-mysql-database) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48595477/insert-in-mysql-database-when-post-from-c-sharp-code-in-persian-language) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52344043/send-persian-string-to-mysql)

Comment: MySQL collations can be applied in a per-table or even per-column basis so you don't need to change the complete database encoding if you don't want to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

درود they way we do that is by using a `utf8mb4_persian_ci`

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (

) DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4_persian_ci
```

This is how we would go about doing that.
Persian Text will be saved using utf8mb4 it also Supports Emoji's and Much Much more !

Answer (score 0):

UTF-8 characters may be any length from 1 to 4 bytes. MySQL made a goof, and their `utf8` collation only allows 1 to 3 bytes. 4-byte characters (which include emoji) cannot be saved in MySQL's `utf8` collation. Instead, you must use `utf8mb4`, which is a newer collation designed to fix the previous error.

So you want `utf8mb4_persian_ci`.

Comment: those with Persian text

Comment: I see no reason that they should give you problems. `utf8mb4` allows *up to* 4 bytes per character. Single-byte characters, such as ASCII, will still work fine.